# Get only elements that are not repeating in an XML

Tags: xslt, duplicates

I have a scenario where the XML doc contains some nodes that are repeating. I want to get rid of all such nodes.
Please note that this is **not** "***Removing Duplicates***". I want to completely remove all entries of those nodes that are occuring more than once.

Ex
My XML

```
<ReadUserOBSResponse>
 <UserOBS>
  <OBSObjectId>1510</OBSObjectId>
  <UserObjectId>443</UserObjectId>
 </UserOBS>
 <UserOBS>
  <OBSObjectId>540</OBSObjectId>
  <UserObjectId>514</UserObjectId>
 </UserOBS>
 <UserOBS>
  <OBSObjectId>1521</OBSObjectId>
  <UserObjectId>514</UserObjectId>
 </UserOBS>
 <UserOBS>
  <OBSObjectId>547</OBSObjectId>
  <UserObjectId>544</UserObjectId>
 </UserOBS>
</ReadUserOBSResponse>
```

Desired Output : I want to remove both entries with UserObjectId 514

```
<ReadUserOBSResponse>
 <UserOBS>
  <OBSObjectId>1510</OBSObjectId>
  <UserObjectId>443</UserObjectId>
 </UserOBS>
 <UserOBS>
  <OBSObjectId>547</OBSObjectId>
  <UserObjectId>544</UserObjectId>
 </UserOBS>
</ReadUserOBSResponse>
```

I've done some things, but its not working. My Idea was to count the nodes with UserObjectId as the current value, put this in an `xsl:if` and then print the nodes.
But I'm not sure how to write this snippet.

Comment: _"I've done some things, but its not working"_ -- WHAT have you done so far?

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you need.

It has a template for `UserOBS` elements that checks whether there is exactly one `UserOBS` child of its parent that has the same value for `UserObjectId`. If so the entire node is copied to the output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/ReadUserOBSResponse">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="UserOBS">
        <xsl:if test="count(../UserOBS[UserObjectId = current()/UserObjectId]) = 1">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReadUserOBSResponse>
   <UserOBS>
      <OBSObjectId>1510</OBSObjectId>
      <UserObjectId>443</UserObjectId>
   </UserOBS>
   <UserOBS>
      <OBSObjectId>547</OBSObjectId>
      <UserObjectId>544</UserObjectId>
   </UserOBS>
</ReadUserOBSResponse>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very efficient (and concise) approach that uses keys:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:key name="kUOId" match="UserOBS" use="UserObjectId" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="UserOBS[key('kUOId', UserObjectId)[2]]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<ReadUserOBSResponse>
  <UserOBS>
    <OBSObjectId>1510</OBSObjectId>
    <UserObjectId>443</UserObjectId>
  </UserOBS>
  <UserOBS>
    <OBSObjectId>547</OBSObjectId>
    <UserObjectId>544</UserObjectId>
  </UserOBS>
</ReadUserOBSResponse>
```

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler in XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="UserObs" group-by="UserObjectId">
  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[last()=1]"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```